# WSO2 EMM HTTP Status 400 - Your request is malformed when logging into Publisher

Tags: wso2

I am using WSO2 EMM 1.1.0
I logged into the publisher and successfully added an android application.
I then tried to add the IOS version of the application and nothing happened on the web page when I pressed submit. It did tell me that the ipa was successfully uploaded. I looked in the wso2carbon.log file and it was complaining that an application already existed with the same name. So I tried to fix it on the add application page but I got an error back. Now I cannot access the publisher pages at all. I get the following error:

HTTP Status 400 - Your request is malformed

The wso2carbon.log file shows these errors around the time I tried to add the new application:

Invoking lifecycle action "Create" failed {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.d$
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Preprequest action must be completed before Create

Failed to add artifact: artifact id: 0e7f12c8-6241-45ab-b076-f3a8a85d09f5. Governance artif$
org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.exception.GovernanceException: Governance artifact Mobile Check Payment already exists at /mobileapps/admin/ios/Mobile Check Payment/1.0

I believe I have encountered this existing bug:

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-729

How can I clear out the broken application from the Publisher or worse how can I completely reset the Publisher data store?

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: please follow this doc and test it again.  https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Creating+an+iOS+Application

Comment: Those are the steps that I followed and led to the broken entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can login to carbon console

Eg:

```
https://localhost:9443/carbon/
```

From the left menu select Resources -> Browse

From the Browse page select Detailed View Tab

Select _system -> governance -> mobileapp ->  -> ios.

Select your app and delete it from publisher.

This issue is identified as an intermittent issue. If your iOS .IPA file is a large file you have to wait until the app get completely uploaded to the server before submitting the app. Once you upload the iOS app you will be notified that the app is uploaded successfully. Then you can submit it with other info such as name, banner, icons.

Comment: that removed the application from the publisher. Now I cannot get into the /emm/apps/management pages. It is throwing the following error in the wso2carbon.log file

Comment: this is  ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr.XMLHttpRequestHostObject} -  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target {org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr.XMLHttpRequestHostObject}
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested targetthe error

Comment: Did you configure EMM according to docs https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Deployment+Guide